# What is the difference between the [product-identification] and [materials-identification] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

The question title says it all really. [materials-identification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials-identification) is only used in four questions, and I'm struggling to see why it exists. [product-information](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-information) is far more established as a tag, and I have no issue with it.

So, should [materials-identification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials-identification) exist?

Specifically it's tagged on:

- [What book contains the rules for Riot Shields?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101444/what-book-contains-the-rules-for-riot-shields)
- [What book had Rituals to "upgrade" animal companions to keep them viable at higher levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124674/what-book-had-rituals-to-upgrade-animal-companions-to-keep-them-viable-at-high)
- [Where do I find Greater Globe of Invulnerability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108192/where-do-i-find-greater-globe-of-invulnerability)
- [What feat heals a spell's caster when that spell deals damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103951/what-feat-heals-a-spells-caster-when-that-spell-deals-damage)

Answer (score 11):

It looks like this cropped up in July 2017 in response to [a discussion around synonymising content-identification and product-identification together](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7178/1204). Specifically, [SevenSidedDie suggested](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7187/1204) they shouldn't get synonymised directly together, but could be both synonymised into materials-identification.

It didn't catch on, but its introduction might've just gone unnoticed.

I think we ought to retag these into content-identification or product-identification case by case and let the tag vanish again for now, unless/until we're ready to merge them together.

---

Aug 7 2018: I've just now removed the tag from those questions and replaced it with [content-identification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-identification) or [product-identification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-identification).